# Stopping the loop to work on few worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim MyRefAddr As String
    Dim MyCopyAddr As String
    Dim MyDestAddr As String
    Dim NoOfCols As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Distributor As String
    Dim Z As Double
    Dim Davg As Double
    Dim LT As Long
    Dim temp As Long

    Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Norms"
    Sheets("Norms").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "SKU"
    MyCopyAddr = Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Address
    Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet3!RC"
    Range(MyCopyAddr).AutoFill Destination:=Range(MyCopyAddr + ":A69")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Norms" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then
            Range("B5").Select
            Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
            MyRefAddr = ActiveCell.Address
            NoOfCols = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("B5:" + MyRefAddr))
            'STDEV
            MyCopyAddr = Range(MyRefAddr).Offset(-1, 1).Address
            Range(MyRefAddr).Offset(-1, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = "Sigma D"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Whats the error in the code. THe code is going to "norms" sheet and calculating there inspite of excluding it

Comment: @simoco Can you plzz explain or give it a try..  
 I m new to this stuff.

Comment: what explain? I don't understand your question

Comment: I have used 
If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Norms" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then
to prevent the code to go to mentioned sheets like "Norms". but 
it is not happening

Comment: code works fine for me. Try to change `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets`

Comment: 1) your `IF` works, but 2) in your loop `Range("B5").Select` always refers to range on _active sheet_ (`Norms` in your case) rather than on sheet that is current in loop (`ws`). Also check this [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: That's the point i am trying to make . Actually I don't want the code to go to Norms Sheet anytime .. 
Changed  Range("B5").Select to 
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Select

Still it is computing things in Norms Sheet 

I know this is silly, but its troubling me from a lot of time

Comment: I've already told you what to do! `ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Select` and `Range("B5").Select` the same - they both referce to _active sheet_ which is `Norms` because you selected it few lines before: `Sheets("Norms").Select`. Have you read the post I gave you the link in comments above: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)??? Read it attentively and rewrite your code

Comment: Changed Code to  this as suggested in the post

Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Norms"
    
        
    With Sheets("Norms").Range("A1")
    
    ActiveCell.Value = "SKU"
    
    MyCopyAddr = Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Address
    Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet3!RC"
    Range(MyCopyAddr).AutoFill Destination:=Range(MyCopyAddr + ":A69")
    
    End With


'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
 If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Norms" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then


Again computing the norms , no relied

Comment: You need to activate the ws Worksheet right after your 'If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" ..... ' line

Answer (score 0):

The code calculate in the Norm sheet because it's the active worksheet.  All the range in the loop refer to the active sheet.  You should avoid using select and activate :

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

EDIT : Made some cleanup and removed all 'Select' and 'Activate'

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NoOfCols As Integer
    Dim workSheetNorm As Worksheet, cell As Range

    Set workSheetNorm = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1))
    'workSheetNorm.Name = "Norms"


    Set cell = workSheetNorm.Range("A1")
    cell.Value = "SKU"

    Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet3!RC"
    cell.Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=workSheetNorm.Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), "A69")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Norms" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then
            Set cell = ws.Range("B5", ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

            NoOfCols = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(cell)
            'STDEV
            cell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "Sigma D"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to do the same using With Command 
With Sheets("Norms").Range("A1")
   
    ActiveCell.Value = "SKU"
    
    MyCopyAddr = Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Address
    Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet3!RC"
    Range(MyCopyAddr).AutoFill Destination:=Range(MyCopyAddr + ":A69")
    
    End With

MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Name)
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Norms" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then                
   Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
   MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Name)

no relief

Comment: Can you please help me figure this out ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reference all Ranges to `ws`?
Something like this?:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Norms" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then
        ws.Range("B5").Select 
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Select 
        MyRefAddr = ActiveCell.Address 
        NoOfCols = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(ws.Range("B5:" + MyRefAddr)) 'STDEV 
        MyCopyAddr = ws.Range(MyRefAddr).Offset(-1, 1).Address 
        ws.Range(MyRefAddr).Offset(-1, 1).Select 
        ActiveCell.Value = "Sigma D" 
    End If 
Next ws
```